# Receive multipart data from the client

Tags: java, rest, media-type

I have s service which return the multipart data like this :

```
public ResponseEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> getData(){

    MultiValueMap<String, Object> resultMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();

    //Add a pdf doc 
    resultMap.add("file", new byte[]);
    resultMap.add("object",new String("Hello");
}
```

this multivaluemap is returned.

Now, I am not sure how to go about with the client code for this :

```
ResponseEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> response = restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().encode().toUri(), HttpMethod.GET,entity,**?**);
```

Is this the right way to invoke and get the results?If so what would be the class name for **?** . Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Yes that is the only way you can do it, because there are heterogeneous objects as values in `multivaluemap`, but it will be little bit tricky logic while using them from response object

Comment: Thanks Deadpool. I faced some other issue this time . Posted it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53340819/urldecoder-illegal-hex-characters-in-escape-pattern-for-multipart-data